# Django custom reverse manager using a through model

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have a set of models where a `Student` is assigned multiple `Class`es via another model, `ClassStudentMapping`, which has a field where I can set which classes a student has on a particular day.

models.py

```
class Student (models.Model):
    ...


class Class(models.Model):
    ...
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='classes', through="ClassStudentMapping")


class ClassStudentMapping(models.Model):
    class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = [
        ('0', 'Monday'),
        ('1', 'Tuesday'),
        ('2', 'Wednesday'),
        ('3', 'Thursday'),
        ('4', 'Friday'),
        ('5', 'Saturday'), 
        ('6', 'Sunday'),
    ]
    days = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK), size=20, default=list(range(0,7)))
```

So if `this_student` is an instance of `Student`, then I can obviously get all the classes a student has via `student.classes.all()`.  I want to be able to use a custom manager to call a custom query to get all the classes a student has *on the current day*.

```
class ClassTodayManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(classstudentmapping__days__contains=[str(datetime.today().weekday())])
```

But I can't figure out where to put this manager so that I can invoke it via something like `student.today_classes.all()`.

Following the Django docs rather naively, I tried:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    today_classes = ClassTodayManager()
```

But that resulted in, "AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'today_classes'.

I realized I needed a [custom reverse manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-custom-reverse-manager), and tried `student.classes(manager='today_classes')`.

But weirdly that is returning multiples of every result -- two for a class that only happens Wednesdays and 9 (!) for a class that happens all seven days of the week -- and it has disabled the default `Class.objects.all()` call, which I still need to be able to call as well.

I think there is a complication here related to the `through` model that I don't understand how to address and that makes all the other examples I can find online irrelevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your manager’s implementation so you don’t do the filtering by overriding the `get_queryset` method, then this should set your manager to be used in reverse relations:

```py
class Classes(model):
    ...
    objects = ClassTodayManager()
    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'objects'
```

The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#base-manager-name) should shed more light on this. It also mentions [somewhere](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Model._base_manager) in the docs not to override the `get_queryset` method in any way that filters out objects if you are going to replace the base manager.

In your case I would not override `get_queryset` and instead move that logic to a `today_classes` method like this:

```py
class ClassesTodayManager(Manager):
    def today_classes(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(classstudentmapping__days__contains=[str(datetime.today().weekday())])
```

Then you can access it like so: `student.classes.today_classes()...`

Comment: Thanks, this gets at what I was looking for and accomplishes it in a straightforward way.

Comment: Just pointing out that `‘objects’` is using special characters and not `''` single quotes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of custom manager, I think its better if you can use a property method like this:

```
class Student (models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def today_classes(self):
       return self.classes.filter(classstudentmapping__days__contains=[str(datetime.today().weekday())])


# Usage:
student.today_classes # will return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want this logic to reside in the `Student` model.  Using a custom manager permits me to define the custom logic with the appropriate model it is manipulating.